# How to make multiple images resposive

Tags: html, css

so i have 8 images in a div and i want to make it resposive

at 1200px I want it to be like[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxOjc.jpg)

At 800px to be like[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdXLg.jpg)

And At 650 px to be like[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho7Vj.jpg)

Sorry I don't have a code to show

Comment: Your images need to be inside <div>. Each one will have a width. Lets say it's 25%. If you need to make it 50% on 800px and below, you can add the css inside something called "Media query". Example : @media (max-width: 800px)  {/*special css here*/}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have 2 things to tackle here: First, you need to set the different breakpoints you need using media-queries in your CSS file. Second, you need to style your grid layout.

So for media-queries, I personally like to go mobile-first, so my media queries are min-width. You start with your small screen rules first, then you only change the styling that needs to change in the bigger screen media-queries.

```
.box{
   background-color: #CCCCCC;
   padding: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 650px){
   .box{
      padding: 20px;
   }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px){
   .box{
      padding: 30px;
   }
}
```

So in this example above, `.box` has background-color and padding. I only set the background-color once because it will be used in all media-queries following it. So the first styles you set could work for all screen sizes, unless you overwrite them in the following media-queries. Once the browser window is 650px wide or bigger, it will go to your next media-query styling. So the padding of .box will become 20px, and once the browser window reaches 1200px, the padding will change to 30px.

Now that you understand media-queries, let's move to Flexbox.

You need to set the parent div surrounding the inner boxes (those houses like in your design example), we'll use `.grid-layout`

```
<div class="grid-layout">
   <div class="box">
   </div>
   <div class="box">
   </div>
   <div class="box">
   </div>
   <div class="box">
   </div>
</div>
```

We now want to give our styling to both `.grid-layout` and `.box` in our CSS and media queries. You can look on youtube FLEXBOX, and learn the different values for flex-direction, align-items, justify-content & flex-wrap. They are your new best friends.

```
.grid-layout{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
.box{
   width: 100%;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 650px){
   .box{
      width: calc(50% - 20px);
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
   }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px){
   .box{
      width: calc(33.33% - 20px);
   }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px){
   .box{
      width: calc(25% - 60px);
      margin-left: 30px;
      margin-right: 30px;
     margin-bottom: 60px;
   }
}
```

Theres a few complications you might need to test out and learn about but the `.box` widths and margins in the media queries really is what you need to go from 1 column to 2, to 3, to 4.

Here's a link to a codepen showing all this and a little more.
https://codepen.io/MateoStabio/pen/xxRZXwO

Answer (score 1):

You can use @media screen and (max-width: ) in your stylesheet to filter out some CSS to only work when the max width of the screen is whatever you set it as.

Comment: Thanks for your help but can u explain me in code please?

Comment: I'll give you an example, if I wanted to make the font different on mobile I can do it like this:
`@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
p {
    font-family; Arial;
}
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>How to make multiple images resposive</title>
<style type="text/css">
        .container{
            padding: 0 15px;
        }
        *{
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px
        }

        .media-warper {
            margin: 0 -15px;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .media-warper .media-item {
            padding: 0 15px;
            width: 25%;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        .media-warper .media-item .media-img {
            max-width: 100%;
            display: block;
        }

        @media(max-width: 767px){
        .media-warper .media-item {
            width: 25%;
        }

        }
        @media(max-width: 576px){
        .media-warper .media-item { 
            width:100%;
        }
    
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="media-warper">
        <div class="media-item">
          <img src="img-url" alt="" class="media-img">
        </div>
         <div class="media-item">
          <img src="img-url" alt="" class="media-img">
        </div>
         <div class="media-item">
          <img src="img-url" alt="" class="media-img">
        </div>
         <div class="media-item">
          <img src="img-url" alt="" class="media-img">
        </div>
        <div class="media-item">
          <img src="img-url" alt="" class="media-img">
        </div>
         <div class="media-item">
          <img src="img-url" alt="" class="media-img">
        </div>
         <div class="media-item">
          <img src="img-url" alt="" class="media-img">
        </div>
         <div class="media-item">
          <img src="img-url" alt="" class="media-img">
        </div>

    </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap to make your images responsive. It is very simple to do. Bootstrap is the most popular CSS Framework for developing responsive and mobile-first websites.

For reference go to [bootstrap images](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/images/)

Here is an example for you..! Open this code in full page view and change width of your browser or inspect with toggle device toolbar, you can see how properly it works...!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Responsive Images</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row pl-3 pr-3">
        <img class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-3" src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800" alt="">
        <img class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-3" src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800" alt="">
        <img class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-3" src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800" alt="">
        <img class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-3" src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800" alt="">
        <img class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-3" src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800" alt="">
        <img class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-3" src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800" alt="">
        <img class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-3" src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800" alt="">
        <img class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mt-3" src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800" alt="">
    </div>








    <!-- Bootstrap scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```